# applying mirror then resetting loc and rot does not set mirror properly

Tags: modeling, mirror

modleing a head. steps taken: get circle 8 sides. set aline to view, shape circle to eye, add mirror. reset location to 0, reset rotation to 0. this is what I end up with. the eyes are too close together. how do I get the mirrored eye to actaully be where it is suppose to be in the referecnce photo? I even reset the reference photo to center in the 3d viwer and it still does not set the mirrored eye in center of eye.

file and photo inclused in this post. sized down so I can uploaded it

[image]

[image: Photo centered in 3D viewer]

[image: reference photo]
[image: Photo not centered in 3D viewer]

Comment: The object is mirrored from its center. Place it at the middle of the eyes (object mode) then move the vertices upon the eyes (edit mode). Work with scale applied, scale = 1 (it is better)

Comment: OK did it, I am still getting the same results - just like in the image centered in 3D viewer. where the mirroed is off to the Stage right ending in middle of right eye. -- scale applied -- pls explain matbe thats it. How do I check that? @lemon

Comment: @lemon I'm lookking for better photos too, maybe that one is not square on looking forward photo. I too think her face itself is asymmetrical more then it is symmetrical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply rotation and scale (scale is not need here but it is better for the future) :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then choose '*rotation & scale*'

[image]

- Now set the 3D cursor at the center of the 3D space (as the picture is centered also) : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then cursor to center
- Then place the object to the center : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then selection to cursor
- Go to edit mode and replace the eye

The left part (her right) is a bit offset... but no human face is totally symetrical...
[image]

Comment: thanks.. for the step by step, did something close to that. didn't pick the rot and scale selection, the other two I did instead.  but no human face is totally symetrical. yes, but I'm begining to think her face is totally wacked out of symetrical-isim.

Comment: how are you getting the inner upper side of the eye to be where the selection goes to get center?

Comment: The mirror mirrors from the center of the object (the big orange dot), so if it stays in place (edit mode), moving the vertices keeps this center in place... so the mirrored part move in consequence... is that what you wanted to know ?

Comment: ok got it as close as I think I will using yours and this https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html @lemon

thanks for all of your help...

Comment: yes ! the documentation is a good starting point !

Comment: yeah but I live by, if all else fails read the instructions.. this stimulates the brain better then reading documentation that tends to put anyone to sleep. I tweeked it a bit by repeating the proccess adding moving the 3D cursor and resetting the orgion alt+ctrl+shift+c getting it rather spot on. then leaving it like you where getting it.